# AttributeError: module 'viewflow.nodes' has no attribute 'Obsolete'

Tags: django-viewflow

I am new to viewflow. I am just trying to create a worflow.

flows.py

```
from viewflow import rest

from viewflow.base import this, Flow

from viewflow.rest import flow
from viewflow.rest.views import CreateProcessView

from .models import FormInstanceProcess


@rest.register
class FormFlow(Flow):
    process_class = FormInstanceProcess

    create_form = (
        flow.Start(CreateProcessView, fields=["asset", "attributes"])
        .Available(
            lambda user: True
        )
        .Next(this.end_process)
    )

end_process = flow.End()
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from viewflow.models import Process

User = get_user_model()


class FormInstanceProcess(Process):
    asset = models.CharField(max_length=236)
```

helloworld/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from viewflow.rest.viewset import FlowViewSet
from .flows import FormFlow

form_flow_urls = FlowViewSet(FormFlow).urls


app_name = "helloworld"
urlpatterns = [
    path("workflow/", include((form_flow_urls, "form"), namespace="form_flow")),

]
```

When i try to run python manage.py makemigrations command, It gives me error:
AttributeError: module 'viewflow.nodes' has no attribute 'Obsolete'
Please tell me what is wrong here or what am i missing.

Comment: Sine you've using PRO version with REST api it's better to contact to the support directly https://viewflow.io/#contactus